# Repeat the task of exporting multiple Panda datames into multiple csv-files

Tags: pandas, dataframe, csv, for-loop

I'm somewhat new to Pandas/Python (more into SAS), but my task is the following: I have four Pandas dataframes, and I would like to export each of them into a separate csv-file. The name of the csv should be the same as the original dataframe (forsyning.csv, inntak.csv etc).

So far I've made a list with the names of the dataframes, and then tried to put the list through a for-loop in order to generate one csv after another. But I've only made it half-way through. My code so far:

```
df_list = ['forsyning', 'inntak', 'behandling', 'transport']

for i in df_list:  
    i.to_csv('{}.csv'.format(i), index=False, decimal=',', sep=';')
```

What I believe is missing is a proper reference where it says "i.to_csv" in my code above as it now only give me the error "'str' object has no attribute 'to_csv'". I justs don't know how to twist this code the right way - appreciate any advice in this matter. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If need write list of DataFrames to files you need 2 lists - first for DataFrames objects and second for new file names in strings:

```
df_list = [forsyning, inntak, behandling, transport]
names   = ['forsyning', 'inntak', 'behandling', 'transport']
```

So for write use `zip` of both lists and write `df`:

```
for i, df in zip(names, df_list):  
    df.to_csv('{}.csv'.format(i), index=False, decimal=',', sep=';')
```

Or use dictionary of DataFrames and loop values by `dict.items()`:

```
df_dict = {'forsyning': forsyning, 'inntak':inntak,
            'behandling': behandling, 'transport': transport}

for i, df in df_dict.items():  
    df.to_csv('{}.csv'.format(i), index=False, decimal=',', sep=';')
```

Comment: you nailed it...thanks a lot, two lists solved my little problem here

Comment: How could you create the string from the name of the dataframe?  That is generate `'forsyning'` from the first dataframe in the list?  (or the reverse) Then you could eliminate the need to for a second list.

Comment: Honestly, I didn't derive the string from the name of the dataframe - I simply wrote it manually for the sake of this example. But if you have a way to derive the first list based on the second (or vica versa), I'm open for suggestions. Potentially this chould simplify the code even further (eliminate the second list as you mentioned).

Answer (score 0):

Your df_list should have a list of `dataframe` objects. but rather you seem to have the dataframe names in `str` format as elements.
I believe your df_list should be:

```
df_list = [forsyning, inntak, behandling, transport]
```

Comment: agree, that is part of the solution...thanks for comment